# How to make grid gallery in css that occupies empty spaces?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to make a kind of grid gallery. I want it to be responsive so i thought to use float with percentage.

Float in css states it'll occupy empty spaces. (I may be wrong, it might applicable for horizontal only not vertical).

I tried with this code:

**css**

```
#wrapper {
    width:100%;
}
.blocks{
    width:25%;
    float:left;
    border:2px solid green;
    margin:5px;
}
```

**Html**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="blocks">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOPHF.jpg"/>
    </div>
     <div class="blocks">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppuwO.jpg"/>
    </div>
     <div class="blocks">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2QF9.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div class="blocks">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAVHu.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div class="blocks">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpHOP.jpg"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2p7MD/1/)

In the Jsfiddle there is a gap between image 1 and image 5.

Why it is happening how to occupy the empty space.

**Note:** image sizes are changeable so it should dynamically adjust.No need for hardcode.

Any other way to make grid gallery? What is the problem here?

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to work responsively, you'll want

```
display:inline;
```

for this, not

```
float:left;
```

Although that solution will need some additional work, so I have another suggestion.

I think you might be interested in [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) since it is oriented around responsive design and has dedicated grid layouts just for things like this.

Comment: Thanks.Will look at that bootstrap.can you find why the gap in jsfiddle?

Comment: I've understood what you're trying to get at better. I think you should look into Bootstrap, create a row with 3 or 4 columns and fill each column with images. Then things won't be fixed to the same height.

Answer (score 0):

If you have variable height/width blocks, getting a CSS solution which can accommodate any combination will prove frustratingly elusive. You'll likely be best going down a JS route with something like [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Alternatively you can always crop/resize the content of your tiles, and use something [like this](http://cssdeck.com/labs/windows-8-metro-tiles-with-css3)

Comment: Will using a table help? as you shown in the [link](http://cssdeck.com/labs/windows-8-metro-tiles-with-css3)

Comment: It ultimately depends on the effect you want, the content being served and what tradeoffs you're prepared to make

Comment: Okay.can you find why the gap between image 1 and image5 ?

Comment: Its simply how float works in CSS, it works horizontally not vertically once a horizontal float is cleared by crowding